# Raw CSS stylesheet with sass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am building a set of Sass stylesheets using Compass.

I also have a minified copy of bootstrap.css that I would like to include in my deployed site. However, I'm not sure where to keep it or what to do with it.

If I rename it to bootstrap.scss then Compass will pick it up and compile it. This takes a few seconds and I really don't need to add to the build time.

If I leave it named as bootstrap.css then it gets ignored.

Ideally there would be a flag, or some way of telling compass to simply copy that file across rather than attempt to compile it. Does that exist?

Comment: We have our production with `bootstrap.css`. What is stopping you to leave it as is?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean. Where do you store your bootstrap.css?

Comment: Sass isn't supposed to compile .css files.  The `@import` directive has dual behavior in Sass:  compile it into your CSS file if it is a Sass file or write out a CSS `@import` statement if it is a CSS file.

Answer (score 4):

If your CSS file should not be compiled into your finished CSS file, then it should be placed wherever your compiled CSS files go.  However, this is generally not the desired behavior:  a vanilla CSS `@import` generates extra HTTP requests.

There isn't really a down side to having your CSS file compiled by Sass, as the compilation of that file should be cached (unless you're deleting your `.sass-cache` files?).  Sass should only recompile a file if it or something it depends on changes.

Comment: Bootstrap is a standalone css file in this case - it is applied to the  admin area of a site, whereas the main site has its own css which is generated by sass. So rolling it all together would be disadvantageous. I didn't want to keep it in the "compiled css" area because I consider that as a generated directory and expect to be able to clear it out, exclude it from source control etc - to me, it feels messy to include source stylesheets in there.

Comment: re. having it compiled - I often run compass clean as I find compass isn't always completely on-the-ball with picking up changes - and I like to do this before pushing changes to double-check that no errors have been introduced. And the deploy process checks out and builds from scratch. It adds five seconds, which is a lot for something that effectively does nothing. I'm currently trying to reduce compass build times and this seemed like an easy target.

Comment: "So rolling it all together would be disadvantageous" how do you figure?  Depending on the packet size, it is possible (for instance) that a 10kb file and a 15kb file could be sent in a single request.  Unless you're looking at IE limitations or the additional styles are pushing you over the maximum file size a particular browser will cache, you're over-optimizing by splitting them up.

Comment: Not really. A tiny proportion of people would access the admin part of the site. A huge number of people will access the actual site. The two areas are almost completely mutually exclusive. If there were some overlap I'd understand doing that - e.g. there's a lot of page-specific styles in the sass-coded css which are all bundled up together and sent out with every page of the actual site for exactly the reason you're talking about. But it makes zero sense to send out bootstrap.css to all our users just because the admin site needs it.

Comment: You only have 2 choices then:  use a symbolic link (place the .css in your Sass directory and make a symlink of it in your CSS directory) or roll your own script to copy the file where you want it when you go to compile your Sass files.  Sass/Compass cannot do what you want.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like the best option is to roll my own script.